# How to solve "The parameter subscribed_fields is required" error while subscribing a facebook page to app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am creating an app that will pull leads from facebook pages that I manage and update them into Google Sheets subsequently.

I have setup the webhook, generated long lived page access token with following permissions

- manage_pages
- pages_show_list
- leads_retrieval
- ads_management
- ads_read

When I try to subscribe the page to my app using POST request `{page_id}/subscribed_apps` I get the below error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The parameter subscribed_fields is required.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "Fv7RbO8tYqo"
  }
}
```

Researching revealed that facebook has added a new parameter called subscribed_fields in v3.2 api, but I am not sure how values must be passed to that parameter or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 8):

As of facebook api v3.2, I also ran into problems.

Here's what fixed @AdityaChowdhary's original issue:  -add "subscribed_fields: 'leadgen'" as a post parameter, like this:

```
FB.api(
    '/' + page_id + '/subscribed_apps',
    'post',
      { access_token: page_access_token, subscribed_fields: 'leadgen' },
    function (response) {
        console.log('Successfully subscribed page', response);
    });
```

Then, you may run into another error: "To subscribe to the leadgen field, one of these permissions is needed: leads_retrieval".

To prevent the permissions error:  add the "leads_retrieval" permission to the fb.login scope, like this:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
...
}, {scope: ['manage_pages', 'leads_retrieval']});
```

Answer (score 8):

In the new Graph API v3.2, you must pass a parameter `subscribed_fields`, along with the `post` request `me/subscribed_apps` (with the page access token as the access token). You need to pass an array of available subscribable fields that are:

```
[
    feed, mention, name, picture, category, description, conversations,
    branded_camera, feature_access_list, standby,
    messages, messaging_account_linking, messaging_checkout_updates,
    message_echoes, message_deliveries, messaging_game_plays, messaging_optins,
    messaging_optouts, messaging_payments, messaging_postbacks,
    messaging_pre_checkouts, message_reads, messaging_referrals,
    messaging_handovers, messaging_policy_enforcement,
    messaging_page_feedback, messaging_appointments, founded,
    company_overview, mission, products, general_info, leadgen,
    leadgen_fat, location, hours, parking, public_transit,
    page_about_story, phone, email, website, ratings, attire,
    payment_options, culinary_team, general_manager, price_range,
    awards, hometown, current_location, bio, affiliation, birthday,
    personal_info, personal_interests, publisher_subscriptions, members,
    checkins, page_upcoming_change, page_change_proposal,
    merchant_review, product_review, videos, live_videos, registration,
]
```

Like e.g.: `subscribed_fields: ['messages', 'message_deliveries']`

Answer (score 7):

Adding **subscribed_fields=publisher_subscriptions** in request worked for me.
Here is the code:

```
request({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=publisher_subscriptions&access_token=${FB_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`
        },
        (error, response, body) => {
             if (error) {
                console.error('Error while subscription: ', error);
             } else {
                 console.log('Subscription result: ', response.body);
             }
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Im havint the same problem when i try to add a webhook for a facebook_lead ads campaign... it used to work perfectly on previous versions, im passing the scope:
"manage_pages"

```
function myFacebookLogin() {
FB.login(function(response){
  console.log('Successfully logged in', response);
  FB.api('/me/accounts', 
    {limit: 200}, 
    function(response) {
    console.log('Successfully retrieved pages', response);
    var pages = response.data;
    var ul = document.getElementById('list');
    for (var i = 0, len = pages.length; i < len; i++) {
      var page = pages[i];
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = "#";
      a.onclick = subscribeApp.bind(this, page.id, page.access_token);
      a.innerHTML = page.name;
      li.appendChild(a);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  });
}, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
```

}

Comment: Hi @solar_confine

Answer (score 1):

For the fb.login you cant use 'manage_pages' as scope please try to use following:

```
{scope: ['pages_show_list','leads_retrieval']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this can help for you guys:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/#Creating

like this in form of POST request:
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/me/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=

So you need create this. :)

I have some issue with permissions, what is weird because I double checked my page permissions here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken
and seemingly I have the permissons that is missed in the message of the fb error response.

I got this response:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#200) To subscribe to the feed field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the mention field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the name field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the picture field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the category field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the description field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the conversations field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the branded_camera field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the feature_access_list field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the standby field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messages field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_account_linking field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_checkout_updates field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the message_echoes field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the message_deliveries field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_game_plays field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_optins field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_optouts field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_payments field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_postbacks field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_pre_checkouts field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the message_reads field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_referrals field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_handovers field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_policy_enforcement field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_page_feedback field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the messaging_appointments field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the founded field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the company_overview field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the mission field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the products field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the general_info field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the leadgen field, one of these permissions is needed: leads_retrieval. To subscribe to the leadgen_fat field, one of these permissions is needed: leads_retrieval. To subscribe to the location field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the hours field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the parking field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the public_transit field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the page_about_story field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the phone field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the email field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the website field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the ratings field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the attire field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the payment_options field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the culinary_team field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the general_manager field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the price_range field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the awards field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the hometown field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the current_location field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the bio field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the affiliation field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the birthday field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the personal_info field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the personal_interests field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the publisher_subscriptions field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the members field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the checkins field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the page_upcoming_change field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the page_change_proposal field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the merchant_review field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the product_review field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the videos field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the live_videos field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages. To subscribe to the registration field, one of these permissions is needed: manage_pages",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "HTI8+tPvJZt"
}
```

}

But I hope you can avoid this error. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to successfully susbscibe the page to the app but now I am getting error 102 with an error message "Server Failure" while firing the test lead. Screenshot of error - https://prnt.sc/lwtr9p